# Write to file from different functions(python)

Tags: python

is it possible to write to a single file from different function python.

```
from __future__ import print_function
f = open("txt.txt", "wb")
def f1():
   ...write to txt.txt
def f2():
   ...write to txt.txt
```

is it possible?

Comment: Yes, of course that's possible. Why not make the functions take a file handle as a parameter?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Yes it is possible.  To ask a good question here, it is good to show what you've tried - for instance did you try passing `f` into the functions and then using `f.write()` or similar?

Comment: Sure! You should test it out for yourself. And as jon & Richard said, you should pass the file handle as an arg to your functions.

Comment: BTW - from your initial import line, it looks like you're using Python 2.x If you're just starting out and there's no really good reason (e.g. *"I have to maintain a Python 2 codebase"*) - I highly recommend using Python 3, rather than a deprecated language whose support will cease quite soon.

Comment: @JRichardSnape "Quite soon" is a bit of an exaggeration. There hasn't been any announcement yet as to when Python 2.7 support will end, and a 2.7.12 was released just one month ago. But yes, Python 3 is preferred for newcomers to the language.

Comment: @chepner actually, there is https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: That's 3 1/2 *years* from now, and even PEP-373 doesn't make that sound like a hard date (although I'd be very surprised if they didn't stick to it).

Comment: @chepner Fair enough - soon is a relative term. 3.5 years to death in my world is quite soon for computer support, but I'm used to systems that have run for 20+ years.  As you say, Py 3 is preferred is all I'm saying, really.

Answer (score 1):

Just taking the previous suggestions and putting it into code.  Thanks all.

**functions.py:**

```
def f1(file):
    file.write("Function one.")

def f2(file):
    file.write("Function two.")
```

**main.py:**

```
from functions import f1, f2

with open('text.txt','w') as f:
    f1(f)
    f2(f)
```

Comment: Thanks chepner, learning myself.  Was maintaining the the op's **__future__** module naming, but agreed on the file name.